# Site Title and Tagline in Theme Options Page

Tags: php, wp-admin, theme-options, options

I'm using the [*Options Framework Theme*](https://github.com/devinsays/options-framework-theme) to put together an options page. The user(s) I'm building this for would like to be able to edit a few settings directly from this page, including of which - the *Site Title* and *Tagline*.

**Concept:**

[image]

**Options.php:**

```
$options[] = array(
    'name' => __('Site Title', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'desc' => __('The name of your site.', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'id' => 'title',
    'std' => 'PHP CODE FOR SITE TITLE HERE ...',
    'class' => 'medium',
    'type' => 'text');
```

Is there a way to do this (add their own *Site Title* and *Taglines*) within a text-field for example, click the Save Options button to output it to the front-end of the site and display an updated version in the WP API Settings > General Settings sub-menu page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework offers a filter for validating input values inside the *`optionsframework_validate`* function.
Just for reference, here's the relevant part from the file **`wp-content/themes/your-theme/inc/options-framework.php`**:

```
/**
 * Validate Options.
 *
 * This runs after the submit/reset button has been clicked and
 * validates the inputs.
 */
function optionsframework_validate( $input ) {
/* code */
    $clean[$id] = apply_filters( 'of_sanitize_' . $option['type'], $input[$id], $option );
/* code */
```

So, considering that we have the following options in the file **`wp-content/themes/your-theme/options.php`**:

```
$options[] = array(
    'name' => __('Input Text Mini', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'desc' => __('A mini text input field.', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'id' => 'blogname',
    'std' => 'Default',
    'class' => 'mini',
    'type' => 'text');

$options[] = array(
    'name' => __('Input Text', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'desc' => __('A text input field.', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'id' => 'blogdescription',
    'std' => 'Default Value',
    'type' => 'text');
```

And in **`wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php`**, we filter the **`text`** input type (<sup>`of_sanitize_` **+** `text`</sup>) and if it matches our defined ids (`blogname` and `blogdescription`, just like in General Settings), it will update the site options that have the same id.

<sup>*Please note, that this doesn't work the other way around: changes made in `Settings -> General` won't be reflected inside the theme options page...*</sup>

```
add_filter( 'of_sanitize_text', 'wpse_77233_framework_to_settings', 10, 2 );

function wpse_77233_framework_to_settings( $input, $option )
{
    if( 'blogname' == $option['id'] )
        update_option( 'blogname', sanitize_text_field( $input ) );

    if( 'blogdescription' == $option['id'] )
        update_option( 'blogdescription', sanitize_text_field( $input ) );

    return $input;
}
```

Comment: @user1752759, I've updated the Answer with more details about each block of code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Beautiful @brasofilo, just what I was after!  Is it also possible to allow this to work the other way too (Settings > General to the Theme Options page)?

Comment: Possible, it is. I've done it before but cannot find where the code is... Anyway, that's a [new](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), different Question. And a [research here at WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=blogdescription) may bring an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for everything @brasofilo, I'll research and open up a new question for this if needed.  All the best.