# Link blogname and blogdescription to the Options Framework

Tags: php, wp-admin, theme-options, options

I'm putting together a *Theme Options* page, where the user(s) I'm building this for would like to be able to edit a few settings directly from this page, including of which - the *Site Title* and *Tagline*.

With some fantastic help from [brasofilo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/site-title-and-tagline-in-theme-options-page/77238#77238), I have the following...

**/inc/options-framework.php:**

```
/**
 * Validate Options.
 *
 * This runs after the submit/reset button has been clicked and
 * validates the inputs.
 */
function optionsframework_validate( $input ) {
/* code */
    $clean[$id] = apply_filters( 'of_sanitize_' . $option['type'], $input[$id], $option );
/* code */
```

**options.php:**

```
$options[] = array(
    'name' => __('Input Text Mini', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'desc' => __('A mini text input field.', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'id' => 'blogname',
    'std' => 'Default',
    'class' => 'mini',
    'type' => 'text');

$options[] = array(
    'name' => __('Input Text', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'desc' => __('A text input field.', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'id' => 'blogdescription',
    'std' => 'Default Value',
    'type' => 'text');
```

**functions.php:**

```
add_filter( 'of_sanitize_text', 'wpse_77233_framework_to_settings', 10, 2 );

function wpse_77233_framework_to_settings( $input, $option )
{
    if( 'blogname' == $option['id'] )
        update_option( 'blogname', sanitize_text_field( $input ) );

    if( 'blogdescription' == $option['id'] )
        update_option( 'blogdescription', sanitize_text_field( $input ) );

    return $input;
}
```

If the user(s) add in their own blogname/Site Title and blogdescription/Tagline within the *Theme Options* page and then click the Save button, it will output the information to the front-end of the site accordingly, and update the information within each of the text-fields within the WP API *Settings > General* menu.

**Theme Options:**

[image]

**Settings > General:**

[image]

However, if the user(s) make any changes the other way around (within the WP API *Settings > General* menu), the information is output to the front-end of the site, but wont update the fields within the options-framework/Theme Options page.

As I'm fairly new to PHP and how this all works, I was wondering how would I be able to make this work the other way too?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. I suspect that Options Framework is saving and retrieving a different key/value than the one WordPress is using, and you have only half interrupted it. Check the `wp_options` table and see if you are getting two entries for the blog name and description, under different keys.

Comment: You will need to look at the database using the MySQL CLI or something like PhpMyAdmin ( I think Plesk and cPanel both incorporate that but I am not sure. It has been awhile since I used either. )

Comment: What reson do you have to do that at all? why can't you just use `get_option('blogname')` wherever you need it? The whole concept of duplicating that data is wrong IMHO

Comment: Using `get_option('blogname')` will just retrieve the blogname from the Settings > General page. The user(s) I'm building this for would like to be able to edit a few settings directly from this page, including of which, the Site Title and Tagline.

Comment: It is good practice to attribute [where did your code come from](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77233/12615). Having answered the previous Question and knowing the context: why do you need this in the first place? Ain't the Theme options the place to modify the Site name and Tagline? Or are you granting administrative access (settings page) to the client as well? That being said, what you want is possible using the hooks `update_option_blogname` and `update_option_blogdescription`, but **you'll have to learn** how to manipulate your `{$option_name}` as @Milo points out...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys.  There is administrative access on the settings page too and that's pretty much why they would like this feature as they see two different things when going from Settings > General to the Theme Options page.  Sorry brasofilo, I've amended my original post and will delve deeper into the framework using the necessary hooks to get this to work. Thank you all for everything.

Answer (score 2):

I presume your options are being saved in an array under a single key and not actually within the native options WP uses. You can add an action to `update_option_{$option_name}` to update the options famework entry when an option is updated outside your own options panel. You'll have to figure out what key your own options are being saved under.

Comment: This sounds promising...but as I'm relatively new to all of this, I'm unsure of how to implement your suggestion @Milo.  Could you possibly check the framework or point me in the right direction for the relevant code?

Comment: In your options framework setup, look for the name of the key that your options are saved under, there's probably a default value if you haven't set one explicitly. Look in WP docs under `add_action` and the actions reference page for info on hooking a function to the update of the native WP options. Sorry I'm on a slow mobile connection right now, I can give you more info when I'm in office.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses @Milo, there are a few references to the `add_action` and one for `update_option` - `update_option( 'optionsframework', $optionsframework_settings )` in the framework so I'll look into this and hopefully implement your suggestion correctly to make this work.  Thank you for all the help.